# What constitutes a 'good' Terminology tag question?

Tags: discussion, tags

Good questions on StackExchange should show prior research.  There are a number of other sites that are good sources for "What does *** mean?" (I feel like [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/) is really good for technology or broad gaming industry terms, and something like [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/) for more game or genre specific slang and meme type questions).  There have been a couple [terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) questions asked recently that could very easy have been found out from what I feel would be a very intuitive Google search, which would lead to one of these sites in the first couple hits.

Given all these other resources, I tend to think the [terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag is really just down-vote bait.  Is there something I'm missing that would separate a good [terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) question from something that can easily be researched from elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true that many of the questions are very easily answerable by checking a dictionary online, but there are also many cases where that does not work. Some words mean completely different things from game to game, and new words are constantly made up and they don't have their definitions anywhere to be found. That's one of the good uses for [terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), but it's not all about finding definitions for gaming terms, it's also about [finding fitting terms to use](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188858/).

There are also questions that are better answered in this format than they are in a dictionary, such as [What are Dynamic Shadows?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177325/)

You're only seeing part of the picture that is the terminology questions that lack research effort.

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't really considered the "What is a word for this?" style question - I realize it's a lot harder to search for something when you don't know what keywords to use.